# How can I reconnect to BLE device? - UWP

Tags: uwp, bluetooth-lowenergy, win-universal-app, windows-10-universal, gatt

**Both the device id and the address are random that I CANNOT re-use them for `bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync` or `bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromBluetoothAddressAsync`.**

I came up with 2 possible solutions: (1)ConnectionStatusChange & (2)Pairing,

but both cases I have problems.

---

**(1) *MAIN QUESTION***

Before I disconnect, I first save the `bleDevice` as `bleDeviceReconnect`.

Then I unsubscribe, dispose characteristics & service & bluetooth le device, and set them to null.

In the case of reconnecting, instead of `bleDevice = await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(bleDeviceReconnect.DeviceId)`, I'm trying to use:

```
var newSession = GattSession.FromIdAsyn(bleDeviceReconnect.BluetoothDeviceId);
newSession.MaintainConnection = true;
bleDeviceReconnect.ConnectionStatusChanged += ConnectionStatusChangedHandler;
```

**But this case, event handler is NEVER CALLED.**

The handler looks like this:

```
private async void ConnectionStatusChangedHandler(BluetoothLEDevice bluetoothLeDevice, object o)
{
   Debug.WriteLine(bluetoothLeDevice.ConnectionStatus.ToString()) //To check if event comes or not
   if(bluetoothLeDevice.ConnectionStatus.ToString() == "Conncected")
   {
      sList = bluetoothLeDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync(custom service GUID)
      .
      .
      .
   }
}
```

**(2) *Would be great if you can answer this question as well, but you don't have to if you don't know or you don't want***

**Does pairing make the device id or address unchanged?**

I first need to use either one of the methods I said above in order to get the Bluetooth LE object, which I can use it to find the custom service (`sList = bleDevice.GetGattServicesForUuidAsync`) and characteristics (`cList = sList.Services[0].GetCharacteristicsForUuidAsync`), and subscribe/write to the characteristi and so on.

Hence, if the id or address changes, pairing has no meaning.

---

How can I correctly reconnect to BLE device???

I would really appreciate any help.

---

**EDIT**

Richard Zhang - MSFT asked for a minimal runnable demo that I'm adding this:

[Microsoft BluetoothLE Code](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/blob/master/Samples/BluetoothLE/cs)

(1) Scenario2_Client.xaml

Add 2 buttons: [Disconnect] and [Reconnect]

*Disconnection does not happen right away. Please wait at least 5 seconds before you press [Reconncect]

(2) Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs

Declare `private BluetoothLEDevice bluetoothLeDeviceReconnect`

```
private void Disconnect_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   bluetoothLeDeviceReconnect = bluetoothLeDevice;

   RemoveValueChangedHandler();
   selectedCharacteristic?.Service?.Dispose();
   selectedCharacteristic = null;
   service.Dispose();
   service = null;
   bluetoothLeDevice?.Dispose();
   bluetoothLeDevice = null;
   GC.Collect();
}

private void Reconnect_btn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
   var newSession = GattSession.FromIdAsyn(bluetoothLeDeviceReconnect.BluetoothDeviceId);
   newSession.MaintainConnection = true;
   bluetoothLeDeviceReconnect.ConnectionStatusChanged += ConnectionStatusChangedHandler;
}

private async void ConnectionStatusChangedHandler(BluetoothLEDevice bluetoothLeDevice, object o)
{
   SEE ABOVE
}
```

Currently I'm running out of time that I couldn't test this yet.

Lemme know if this doesn't work as what I said! I'll make a GitHub account, upload my project, and copy the link & paste it here.

Comment: Hi, I hope you can provide a minimal runnable demo so we can help you locate the problem. Or you can refer to [Microsoft's Bluetooth connection Sample](https://github.com/microsoft/Windows-universal-samples/tree/master/Samples/BluetoothLE), I tested it, it can get the device from Id normally, which at least shows that the `uuid` of the device does not change after pairing.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the comment. I already read that sample, which I follow exactly the same flow for device searching. My code is like adding two buttons, [Disconnect]&[Reconnect] in Scenario2. Hold on I'll edit my question.

Comment: Hi, `Scenario2_Client.xaml.cs` contains the `ClearBluetoothLEDeviceAsync` method. In **Disconnect**, you can call this method directly, but since `bluetoothLeDevice` is Disposed, you need to re-use `await BluetoothLEDevice.FromIdAsync(selectedBleDeviceId);` to establish device connection before establishing a GATT session.

Comment: Hi, so you mean I need to ADD `var newSession .... Handler` line after the `bleDevice = await....` line, instead of REPLACING that line, right? I'll try it!

Comment: Unfortunately, I tried it but this DID NOT work as well. The handler never gets called just like before.

Comment: Hi, I‘m sorry that my reply didn't help you. Please post your code completely so that we can reproduce your question.

Comment: Hi, actually, your method worked! Thank you so much for your help. I really appreciate it. However, I faced another [issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58587643/getgattservicesasync-throws-hresult0x80000013-error-uwp)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

NVM **It works!**

The mobile app was the problem during the pairing.

Also, I had to **pair AND add the handler** to make it work.

I can get the BluetoothLEDevice object via the handler,
but searching services is now an issue.

Since this is not the same problem I asked in this post, I'll post a new question.

Comment: The new error occurred cuz I forgot to remove the handler dah! Works perfectly now!